# Exclude domains from sends on child business unit level

Tags: dataextensions, filters, sfmc-business-unit, exclusion-script

Working as a Marketing Cloud marketeer in a franchisee setup with 170 child business units I'd like for the franchisee marketeers for every child business unit to be able to always exclude certain domains from being sent to, even though the emails might already exist in their data extensions.

I could possibly do it from the parent level, but to let the franchisees in every business unit know that they own and handle their own data I'd like to teach them how to do this.

So, ie. I'd like to suggest a solution to the franchisee marketeers to automatically exclude emails ending with:

- '6url.com',
- 'aport2000.ru',
- 'ass.pp.ua',
- 'axoskate.com',
- 'backstreet-boys.com',
- 'bodhi.lawlita.com'.

One way to do this is to have the franchisee marketeers filter the individual child business unit master data extensions for emails ending as described above, and then always exclude this filtered data extension, but this would require the franchisee marketeers to always remember to add the exclusion data extension.

**Can anyone suggest a more flexible approach on the child business unit level?**

Thank you

Comment: Hi @EazyE, the reply you refer is actually very helpful. There are more things to consider though. Most of the franchisee marketeers are merely store employees given the responsibility to handle marketing sends. Therefore they seldomly do any advanced stuff and often just do single sends. And only a very few of them are AMPscript capable.

The solution suggested would require my franchisee marketeers to add the exclusion script to every send they do and it would require for them to handle basic AMPScript.

I am not sure this would work, but still I'd like to pursue this as a solution.

Comment: Did you look at the domain exclusion data extension option

Comment: For starters I succeeded in setting up a guide for the franchisee marketeers to use exclusion scripts. Even though being a cumbersome script to include in every send, it's doable. Right now I'm examining pros and cons of enabling and using the custom list detective option for excluding domains. Other solutions would be, as you suggest, creating a domain exclusion data extension, or even creating a content block with the domain exclusion AMPScript inside determining to sent the mail to the individual subscriber or not. There are so many ways to do this, I'm really trying to find the best way.

Comment: Hi @EazyE I made the Domain Exclusion Data Extension solution work now. The first times I tried this approach, I just excluded the Domain Exclusion Data Extension by dragging it to the standard exclusion box.. But, when dragging the Domain Exclusion Data Extension to the Domain Exclusion part under Advanced Exclusion, it works :)